# Get child records based on the PId that is foreign key in parent table - Spring/Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I want to get child records based on the PId that is foreign key in child table.

Parent Table

```
PId     Name
1       Nish
2       Bish
3       Tish
```

Child Table

```
CId     PId     Name
1       1       ABC
2       1       DEF
3       2       XYZ
```

Parent Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="parent")
public class Parent {

    private Integer PId;
    private String name;

    //getter and setters

}
```

Child Enity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="child")
public class Child {

    private Integer CId;
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne
    private Parent parent;

    //getter and setters

}
```

I want to get all child records based on PId exist in Child table. Don't want to get parent records. I have collection of PIds.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create criteria and fetch all children who has parent id like this:

```
public List<Child> getChildsOfParent(Integer parentId) {
       Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
       Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Child.class);
       cr.add(eq("parent.id", parentId));
       return (Child)cr.list();
}
```

you should autowired the hibernate session factory if you are using spring, or you should open session by yourself.

Comment: Thanks @Burask. It's helped me alot. It's worked for me.

Comment: you are welcome @Ankurjain If you want you can mark as correct so others can also understand it works.